# How to get iOS views to resize and reload their content following a call disconnecting?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

We have an iPhone app which makes use of various combinations of tableviews and custom view controllers and even some in app browsers.  The views often have background images, etc.  Everything seems to work, except when a call comes in, and the user switches to the app during the call, the in call status bar pushes down the content of the view.  Then when the call disconnects, the view moves back up, but leaves a gap at the bottom.

Two problems with this:

1. If we have a status bar or ad or whatever on the bottom, while inside the call, it pushes the ad or status bar down covering half of it.  (or in some cases it keeps the ad where it is, and pushes it up on disconnection so it's no longer at the bottom)
2. We want the view to resize and redraw when it moves back up on disconnection, and not have a white bar at the bottom of the screen.

We've tried various options, and none seem to have any effect.

I assume there is something obvious I am missing.

Comment: I have the same problem, Did you find the solution to this situation?

Thanks